# only accept numbers and 4 symbols (+-/*)

Tags: regex

I have an input field that allows the user to enter a calculation such as (10*7+11/10-2) and the result is outputted when submit is pressed.

I need to have validation on my input field so that only numbers and 4 symbols (+-*/) are allowed to be submitted. Here is what I have so far:

```
[0-9]*\+-
```

I just can't grasp the pattern I need.

In case it's relevant, the platform is Java based.

Comment: I suggest putting time apart to learn some regex basics at http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Tip: `/^[0-9*\+-]$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the symbols that you want to match inside the brackets, where the number range is:

```
/^[0-9*\+-]+$/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I type even simple equations such as 10+10 it gives me the Regex Pattern error?

Answer (score 0):

Put the symbols inside the brackets, AND use anchors:

```
/^[0-9*\+-]$/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I type even simple equations such as 10+10 it gives me the Regex Pattern error?

Comment: <f:validateRegex pattern="/^[0-9*\+-]+$/"/>

Comment: JSF? Sorry, don't know quite nothing about it... Check docs... for example, if anchors to field start (`^`) and to field end (`$`) are required / accepted...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the end:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9*\+-]+$"/>
```